# Bash Shell Scripting - Reducing Pipe Lines difficulty

Tags: shell, grep, find

I need to reduce the following into a single `find` statements.

```
$ find . -print | grep dir
$ find . -print | grep ch
```

The only tip was given to me was to read `man` page to manage to do this. I read through it and had the following conclusion, can someone tell me if I am making the right thinking or if they can direct me to a helpful site where I can understand reducing pipe lines more.

Attempts to do this in a single line:

```
$ find . -print | grep dir && grep ch
$ find . -print | grep dir , grep ch
```

or making use of **printf**.

Does the above make sense or will it give me:
*not found*?

Comment: Use `grep -E -e 'dir|ch'`.  It's important to reduce the number of times you execute `find`; it is an expensive operation.

Comment: ah ok! will be trying this out now will confirm if it works in a few sec

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Jonathan Leffler answer works!

Answer (score 4):

Use `find` with `-name` options, connected by `-o` (= logical `or`), like so:

```
find . \( -name '*dir*' -o -name '*ch*' \)
```

Comment: ok so if my top folder is named groc, my sub folder is fruits and i want terminal to find the folders apple and banana inside the folder fruits for example. Is this the right way to write it?
find . \( -groc'*dir*' -o -fruits'*ch*' \) ?? or am I understanding shell wrongly. thank you for patience. I am very new to this and trying to understand and thanks for help

Comment: You need `find groc/fruits -type d \( -name apple -o -name banana \)`. You would get better help (from more people) if you ask this as a separate question, instead of as a comment.

Comment: makes more sense than my thinking thank you ok thkx for suggestion.

Comment: Parenthesis not needed here. So this will work too: `find . -name '*dir*' -o -name '*ch*'`

Answer (score 0):

Both lines use this expression as their input:

```
find . -print
```

So what you will want to do is pipe the result of evaluating that expression to the two grep calls.

```
find . -print | (grep dir; grep ch)
```

Note:
You'll want to be careful of doing something like what you had previously proposed as a solution, because of short circuit evaluation. That is-

```
find . -print | expr1 && expr 2
```

This only evaluates both if expr1 returns True, positive or non null value (because both operands need to be true for and to return true). In your case, you want both grep dir and grep ch to evaluate every time, regardless of whether the first grep found anything.

```
find . -print | expr1 || expr 2
```

This does not evaluate expr2 if expr1 returns True, positive or non null value (Because or requires only one operand to be true in order to return true)

Rather than && or ||, use semi colon.

```
expr1; expr2

echo hello; echo world
```

That is a clean way to group two expressions without one logically dependent on the output of the other.

Comment: I agree with @johnathan leffler. His is probably the better. right solution, but the concepts in my answer was a breakthrough for me when I was taking bash class

Comment: When I used the ; only expression1 was outputted for some reason will tell you if it works when I try it again

Comment: This just doesn't work. E.g. `find . -print | (grep dir; grep ch)` will pipe the output from the `find` command to the first `grep`, which will read until there's no input left. Then the second `grep` command will run with empty input and consequently print nothing at all. Also, `&&` or `||` won't help here.